# Can a Tokamak-Based Mainframe feed Plasma to larger pipe-structure in order to create plasma-based propulsion engines?

Tags: plasma-physics, propulsion

Can a Tokamak-Based Mainframe feed Plasma to larger pipe-like structures in order to create plasma-based propulsion engines?

It is a rather naive question.

Comment: The question seems quite speculative, so I am not sure it can be answered by mainstream Physics.

Answer (score 1):

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tymmhoNbxd0) one can see the construction of a Tokamak .

[Here one can see](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10894-018-0162-5) where the plasma is  confined with the magnetic fields.

> [The tokamak is an experimental machine](https://www.iter.org/mach/Tokamak) designed to harness the energy of fusion. Inside a tokamak, the energy produced through the fusion of atoms is absorbed as heat in the walls of the vessel. Just like a conventional power plant, a fusion power plant will use this heat to produce steam and then electricity by way of turbines and generators. (Scroll down for more about the tokamak.)

In addition to being bulky and a lot of weight, a Tokamak does not produce direct electricity, but uses the heat generated by the plasma of fusion, which plasma is circulating within.

There does not seem to be a cost effective way to take part of the plasma to generate the equivalent of an [ion thruster.](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html) since most of the energy generated goes to heat.

Comment: Thank you for a concise, reasonable answer. I'm by and large interested in the developments at ITER, hence thinking ahead, I wondered whether smaller and more effective Tokamak may have enough energy output to facilitate such a sci-fi scenario. Thank you for you answer!